# Google Maps JS API v3 not functioning properly (can right click, can't drag/zoom, logo at top...)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

thanks for reading.
I've been using the JS version of the Maps v3 API and I can get Geocoding/Directions/Map Markers and all that going but for some reason on this particular map I want in the sidebar of my client's site, the map seems to not load properly.

I've reverted the JS to the [simple sample code on the API documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) and even then, it's still not working. (For my [screenshot](http://alfatrion.com/images/misc/stackoverflow/googlemapv3_notfunctioning.png) I added 'disableDefaultUI: true' for mapOptions)

- I can't mousewheel scroll to zoom.
- I can't click and drag with the mouse.
- The logo and fine print are showing at the top (usually at the
  bottom)
- I can right click and see a context menu (not normal).

I just don't know why the map won't work on this particular page. Is the map_canvas dimensions too small or something? (231px x 231px).

Have you seen or heard of this issue before?

Comment: Without a link to a page that demonstrates the problem there is not much to say.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have the console open, as it can break the map.

When testing, keep the console closed to see results and reopen it, the refresh to see logs.
This sucks, but it is better than pulling your hair out for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

try this code may be help this..

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var geocoder;
      var map;   

 $(document).ready(function() {
     initialize();
  }

      function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.77627, -73.910965);
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
      }

</script>
```

html

```
<div id="map_canvas">

</div>
```